# Best way to perform search on a particular field in mongodb on large data set | Sharding

Tags: mongodb, sharding

I have large set of data (almost 30 millions) in mongodb collection which has `_id`(mongodb default id) `creation_date` (creation date of that document) and `symbol` (predefined only 50 symbols and symbols are constant. Does not varies.). I am searching on two field i.e. `creation_date` and `symbol`. Let say I want last 30 days data for all 50 coins.

**NOTE:** Data in collection are equally divided with 50 symbols.

**Question:** What is best approach to at least make the searching faster.

**What I know which could be potential solution:** Sharding *(on collection)* on date range. May be 1 month range

Please give your approach. Because I am stuck. Actually I haven't tried sharding yet. Would it be good solution.

Comment: What do you mean by "make it faster"? Are you not satisfied with current performance? Did you create any indexes?

Comment: I have done the indexing on ``_id`` . But it isn't working.I thought there must be a way to make data divided into ``symbols`` so that if we query using symbols, this can make things faster.

Comment: Create an index on `creation_date` and/or `symbol`